# Continuity of a linear functional on various spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $X=C[0, 1]$ be the space of all real valued continuous function on $[0, 1].$ Let $T: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a linear functional defined by $T(f)=f(1)$.

Let $X_1=(X, \vert \vert .\vert \vert_1)$

Let $X_2=(X, \vert \vert .\vert \vert_2)$

Let $X_3=(X, \vert \vert .\vert \vert_{\infty})$

where $T$ is continuous?

My thoughts:

$\vert T(f) \vert \leq \vert f(1) \vert \leq \vert \vert f\vert \vert_{\infty}$. i.e $T $ is continuous on $X_3$ and as $ \vert \vert f \vert \vert_1 \leq \vert \vert f \vert \vert_{\infty}$, so $T$ is continuous on $X_1$, but what about $X_2?$

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for the norms $\|f\|_1=\int\limits_0^1|f(t)|dt$ and $\|f\|_2=\sqrt{\int\limits_0^1|f(t)|^2dt}$. The functional $T(f)=f(1)$ isn't continuous with respect to these norms because $f_n(t)=t^n$ define continuous functions with $\|f_n\|_j\to 0$ for $j=1,2$ (just calculate the integrals) but $T(f_n)=f_n(1)=1$.

Comment: yes, so the ineqality $ \vert \vert f\vert \vert_1\leq \vert \vert f \vert \vert_{\infty}$ does not help?

Comment: Or if I change $T(f)=f(0) $ then we should look for other sequence of function?

Comment: Both right. For $T(f)=f(0)$ you can take $f_n(t)=(1-t)^n$. The main thing of course is not to have an explicit formula but to find continuous functions with small integral norm but big value at the point where you evaluate, ''peak functions'' also do the job.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $\|\cdot\|_1 \le \|\cdot\|_\infty$ does not help. From boundedness in the $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm you cannot conclude boundednes in the $\|\cdot\|_1$ norm. Indeed, let $\|T\|_\infty$ be the operator norm of $T$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.
$$|Tf| \le \|T\|_\infty \|f\|_\infty \stackrel{?}{\le } \|T\|_\infty \|f\|_1$$

For that you would need the reverse inequality $\|\cdot\|_\infty \le \|\cdot\|_1$ which does not hold in general.

$T$ is in fact not bounded with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$.

For example, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ consider $f_n \in C[0,1]$ given as

$$  f(t) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x \in \left[0, \frac{n-1}n\right]$} \\
2n^2t+2n(1-n), & \text{if $x \in \left[\frac{n-1}n, 1\right]$}
\end{cases}$$

We have $\|f_n\|_1 = 1$ but $Tf_n = f_n(1) = 2n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So there cannot exist a constant $C > 0$ such that:

$$2n = |Tf_n| \le C\|f_n\|_1 = C, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

The situation is similar with $\|\cdot\|_2$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define $g_n \in C[0,1]$ as

$$  g_n(t) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x \in \left[0, \frac{n-1}n\right]$} \\
\sqrt{2n^2t+2n(1-n)}, & \text{if $x \in \left[\frac{n-1}n, 1\right]$}
\end{cases}$$

We have $\|g_n\|_2 = 1$ but $Tg_n = g_n(1) = \sqrt{2n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So there cannot exist a constant $C > 0$ such that:

$$\sqrt{2n} = |Tg_n| \le C\|g_n\|_2 = C, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Therefore, we conclude that $T$ is not bounded (i.e. continuous) with respect to $\|\cdot\|_1$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$.